# issue while changing theme in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, themes, flutter-bloc, flutter-theme

I am working with theme mode in app, but sometime while changing theme mode to light text widget hide but in dark mode it is visible.

Used platformdispatcher to change theme based on system theme and set brightness accordingly.
so please help, only happen in release mode Thank you.

image show text hide while change in light theme but in dark mode it is visible.[reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaEsf.png)

Comment: you should provide some code